# Strict-Transport-Security on CloudFront with S3 origin?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

My company's site has a static homepage for speed and cost reasons. We use S3 as the origin for CloudFront. Now, we would like to declare Strict-Transport-Security for the entire domain, but S3 seems to not send any headers we specify (beyond ones starting with like x-aws--). CloudFront doesn't seem to have any custom header option either.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not directly possible, though there are some conceivable workarounds... what benefit does HTTP STS give you, though, if the site is 100% static? Or are you wanting it on the "entire domain" for side effects... in the sense that a request directed to the main site will (?) also impose STS on all subdomains?

Comment: Michael While the homepage is static, our backend is not. It's on a subdomain. Yeah, that's the goal.

Answer (score 3):

You can now add HTTP response headers natively in CloudFront (including HSTS), without modifying your origin or writing a function. Create a new response headers policy with your configuration, then attach the policy to one or more cache behaviors.

Documentation is available here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/adding-response-headers.html

Comment: Note that the SecurityHeadersConfig property should be used to configure HSTS, not the CustomHeadersConfig.

Answer (score 1):

David's answer points to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html), which boil down to:

1. Create a Lambda function like so. Note that Lambda@Edge [has a limited set of runtimes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html) and some additional constraints compared to other Lambda functions. For example, all functions must be created in `us-east-1` - CloudFront will automagically replicate them to other regions - layers are not supported, and all triggers must use an explicit ARN - no aliases, or using `$LATEST`.

```js
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
  const headers = response.headers;

  headers['strict-transport-security'] = [{
    key: 'Strict-Transport-Security',
    /* 
     * verify that max-age and 'includeSubdomains' are the settings you want
     */
    value: 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload' 
  }];

  callback(null, response);
};
```

2. [Publish a version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html) and deploy it to Lambda@Edge. You cannot use `$LATEST` or an alias for the next step.
3. Associate the published function version with a CloudFront distribution. If this is a one-off task, it's probably easier to do it [via the Lambda console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-add-triggers-lam-console.html). If you want to associate your function with multple distributions, it's probably easier to use [the CloudFront console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-add-triggers-cf-console.html).
4. You'll want to set the event type as `origin-response` (between S3 and the cache) or `viewer-response` (between cache and browser), and specify the ARN with the version you published above - e.g.

   `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1234567890:function:MY-FUNCTION-NAME:v1`
5. Wait for the distribution to update and test that the headers are present in the response

Answer (score 0):

Starting 7/16/2017, the functionality you were looking for is available via Lambda@Edge, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html for general documentation, or a specific example at https://nvisium.com/blog/2017/08/10/lambda-edge-cloudfront-custom-headers/